# com.apple.iTunes AEDeterminePermissionToAutomateTarget is always return -600

Tags: swift, macos, macos-mojave

```
import ScriptingBridge

class iTunesAccess {
    static func requestAccess() -> Bool {
        guard #available(OSX 10.14, *) else {
            return true
        }
        if var addressDesc = NSAppleEventDescriptor(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.iTunes").aeDesc?.pointee {
            let appleScriptPermission = AEDeterminePermissionToAutomateTarget(&addressDesc, typeWildCard, typeWildCard, true)
            AEDisposeDesc(&addressDesc)
            return appleScriptPermission == noErr
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppleEventsUsageDescription</key>
<string>somedescriprtion</string>
```

iTunes running but i always get -600 osstatus.
How i can fix it?
iTunes bundle id is fine.

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print CFBundleIdentifier' /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/Info.plist
com.apple.iTunes
```

P.S but if i using "com.apple.dt.Xcode" bundle id it works!

P.P.S i found repo https://github.com/melchor629/iTunes-Scrobbler and build it. It works too.

Comment: Is your app sandboxed?  If so, you'll also need an entitlement to send Apple events to iTunes.

Comment: Omg @ChrisN. I completely forgot to do it! Do this as an answer, please, so that I can mark the issue resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good call on the `NSAppleEventsUsageDescription` key — that’s required if you link against the 10.14 SDK — but if your app is sandboxed, you’ll also need an appropriate Apple event entitlement: `com.apple.security.scripting-targets` if you can, or `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events` if you must.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html for more details, including a way to specify *both* entitlements, but only one applies depending on the current OS version.